# protecting contact between aluminium and copper wires

Tags: everyday-chemistry, electrochemistry, metal, surface-chemistry

The quarters in which I live has both aluminum and copper household wiring. This results in corrosion of the contacts and can lead to sparking, overheating, and even fire.

Is there any way to inhibit the corrosion (if not stopping it completely), except for changing the whole wiring?

Answer (score 2):

This may depend on your location and local electrical codes.  I have the same issue in my house.  In the USA, there are NEC (National Electrical Code) compliant wire nuts rated for Al to Cu connections.  These come pre-packed with a protective goop. The goop can also be purchased separately in a tube for use with ordinary wire nuts. You may have to ask at your local electrical supply store.  In my area the pre-packed wire nuts are a distinctive purple color not found on regular wire nuts (for example: [Home Depot Al/Cu nuts](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ideal-Twister-Al-Cu-Wire-Connectors-65-Purple-10-per-Package-30-1765S/202935623)).

For code compliance, use approved solutions only, even if you think you know more chemistry than the electricians. Having your house burn down from a wiring issue is no fun.

Comment: I'd like to add to this, that [interNACHI](https://www.nachi.org/aluminum-wiring.htm) states many of the qualities regarding aluminum for wiring use.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to stop the corrosion unless the two pieces of metal are galvanically separated, that is, in this case, there is no ion-containg water around (I assume it's inside walls/floors/ceilings). I don't think it's really practical in a house where the wires are already mounted inside structures very apt to contain moisture.

Answer (score 0):

Wire nuts are a considerably unfavorable means of connecting the house wiring to stubs for what I presume are your receptacles. It would be far safer for you to purchase the Aluminum compatible receptacles and use the binding screws for the connections. Wire nuts provide too little contact area and offer no heat dissipation ability to deal with the heat generated by the bimetallic interface of the aluminum/copper joint.